# Distributional derivative involving Dirac delta's

Tags: distribution-theory

I am interested in the integral of the product of a spherical Bessel function and it's derivative, for example:
$$I^n_\ell(r,R)\equiv\int dq q^{n+2}j_{\ell}(qr)j_{\ell}^{''}(qR)$$
and we can keep in mind the identity $$\int dq \ q^2 j_{\ell}  \left( q r \right)   j_{\ell}\left( q R \right) =
\frac{\pi}{2 r^2} \delta_D \left( R - r \right)$$
$I^n_\ell(r,R)$ should typically be a distribution. For example for $n=4$ we may write:
$$I^4_\ell(r,R)=\frac{\partial}{\partial^2R}\int dq \ q^2 j_{\ell}  \left( q r \right)   j_{\ell}\left( q R \right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial^2R}\frac{\pi}{2 r^2} \delta_D \left( R - r \right)$$

However I am unsure how to evaluate the rightmost quantity. Another way of writing $I^n_\ell(r,R)$ is (for even $n$ to make things simpler):
$$\int d q q^{n+2}j_{\ell}(qr)\int  dr' \ q^{-2} \delta_D^{''}(r'-R)j_{\ell} \left( q r' \right)=\int  dr'  \delta_D^{''}(r'-R)\int d q q^{n}j_{\ell}(qr)j_{\ell} \left( q r' \right)$$

Hence I am also interested in computing integrals involving a product of Dirac delta (distribitional) derivatives, such as:

$$\int dr' \delta_D''(r'-R)f(r,r')\delta_D^{(n)}(r-r')$$

for some smooth function $f(r,r')$. How can one compute such integrals?